# Can't get Bootstrap to work consistently on a remote server

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, remote-server

I am currently trying to push my website from my computer to a remote server, everything works fine except a few Bootstrap components (carousel and cards) which are animated with JS.

The problem is that locally it works just fine, my divs show up and do their things as expected, but on the remote server its just a blank area.

I tried replacing the CDNs and playing with them but nothing has changed.

Does anybody encountered this issue before or knows how to fix it?

Here are the CDN links in my `<head>`:

```
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<script
  defer
  src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"
></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

I do see errors in my console every time the page loads I get:

> GET coowoork.000webhostapp.com/js/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>   index.html:168
>
> GET coowoork.000webhostapp.com/images/techcrunch.png 404 VM143:137 DomDistiller debug level: 0
>
> GET coowoork.000webhostapp.com/images/techcrunch.png 404

Comment: Does anything show up (errors or warnings) in the browser console when you load the page on the remote server?

Comment: Yes indeed I edited my post with the errors showing up on screen

Comment: [Why you should not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please post the text of your errors.

Comment: I changed it thank you !

Comment: I don't see that `coowoork...` URL anywhere in your code, is that the live server hostname? The first error shows that somewhere in your code is referencing that JS file, which does not exist.

Comment: coowoork is the domain name, and the index.js file is linked at the bottom of my file in the footer that is why it is not here. I have another page with the exact same construction (the same scripts referenced) and it works just fine !

Comment: The error is clear, and that is what you need to be looking at.  Edit your question and show us where and how it is linked. Check your browser's devtools, inspect the network requests on the network tab. Check the console for error.s